# How to avoid outlook mail windows to show on all virtual desktops?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I use two displays - one for the tasks I currently work on and one for Outlook and Teams (this is on Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2  build: 19042.1586)
And since I switch between different types of tasks I have created 4 virtual desktops.
I have set "Show this window on all desktops" for Outlook and Teams.

Lets say I am doing work on virtual desktop 2 and opens an e-mail in Outlook - then the window with this e-mail appears on all my desktops, not only on the one in which I opened it.
This is annoying - the setting is "show **THIS** window....".
I do not want the different e-mail-windows to appear by default on every desktop. After an e-mail-window is opened it is possible to "unset" that it shall be shown on all desktops. Different e-mails may be relevant for different tasks so it is natural that an e-mail doesn't show up on every desktop by default.

I believe this worked well before the last windows update.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start > Settings > System > Multitasking.
Scroll down to **Virtual desktops** and change **Only the desktop I’m using** to All desktops using the dropdown menu.
Close the Settings app.

[image]

Comment: this seems not working ...